# how to solve [dart] [sqlite] Warning: sqlite.Database.close(): 2 statements still open

Tags: sqlite, dart

ubuntu 16.04
dart sdk 1.19
sqlite 0.4.0

1. I do

```
 ...

 var db = new sqlite.Database("pathtosqlite")

 ...
```

2. I get a database connection and pass it through some functions

```
 ...

 var x = await doStuff(db); (doing several db.query() calls)
db.close()

 ...
```

3. but then I always get an error saying

```
 ...

 Warning: sqlite.Database.close(): 2 statements still open.

 finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

 ...
```

any tips on what Im doing wrong?

Comment: I looked at the implementation (https://github.com/pylaligand/dart-sqlite) and I found that it are slightly incomplete, and for this reason you can not use it properly. I found a bug in the implementation and I reccomend you to contact the developer. I think that they will modify their work and this problem will not arise.